# golang I can't convert "0x000000800"

Tags: go

Hello I need to output 1 after converting this value "0x00000800"
Even if I convert this value("0x00000800")  to 2048, it is enough.

```
fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa((0x00000800 >> 11) & 0x1F)) //working correctly
    
    //but my value comes as string
    src:= "0x00000800"
    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa((src >> 11) & 0x1F)) //not working properly
```

[https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Convert_data_units('Bits%20(b)','Bits%20(b)')&input=MHgwMDAwMDgwMA](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Convert_data_units(%27Bits%20(b)%27,%27Bits%20(b)%27)&input=MHgwMDAwMDgwMA)

https://play.golang.org/p/Sb39Ihxi3Kx

Comment: Edit the question to describe how the numeric value is encoded.  Is it a single bit? Is it a byte?

Comment: Strings do not allow bitshifts. You got your braces wrong.

Comment: @Volker I know but I don't know how to convert this string value?

Comment: Shouldn't the second version use `Atoi`?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco strconv.Atoi: parsing "0x00000800": invalid syntax

Comment: Try [ParseInt](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/xJWyBLf4bir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itoa isn't what you are looking for

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa((0x00000800 >> 11) & 0x1F)) //working correctly

    //but my value comes as string
    src := "0x00000800"
    // src[2:]   removes 0x
    // base 16 hexadecimal
    // bit size of int to convert to
    fmt.Println(strconv.ParseInt(src[2:], 16, 64))
}
```